# Can I open and start an AppleScript-.scpt-program (Name is progName.scpt) with one click or a double-click?

Tags: applescript

On my desktop I have several program-icons and all contains AppleScript-.scpt-programs. To start such a program, I must before load the program with a double-click and then make a click on the run-button. Can I avoid this without transfer the scpt-progam to an app-program.

Comment: If they don’t have to be on the desktop, you can use the [Script menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/UsetheSystem-WideScriptMenu.html).

Comment: You could change the file associations (in Finder, File > Get Info > Open With) so those .scpt files open in a script runner instead of a script editor when double-clicked. (You may have to write the runner app yourself, as a simple AppleScript applet with an `open` handler that calls `run script`.) Or create a Quick Action (accessible in Finder via right-click) in Automator/Shortcuts to run the selected script. Though why not just save those AppleScripts in .app format? That’s what it’s for, after all.

Comment: If you would consider saving scripts in the text-based `.applescript` format rather than a pre-compiled `.scpt` format, then adding an appropriate shebang as the first line, namely `#!/usr/bin/env osascript -s s` and making the file executable (in a terminal, you can execute `chmod +x /path/to/your.applescript`), then double-clicking it will now have it launch your default terminal program to execute the AppleScript by way of `osascript`.